# Same strings, different encoding, but not equal in Ruby

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii-8bit

Can anyone explain what's going on with this code?

```
s1 = "\x20".force_encoding 'UTF-8'
s2 = "\x20".force_encoding 'ASCII-8BIT'
puts "s1 == s2: #{s1 == s2}"

s3 = "\xAB".force_encoding 'UTF-8'
s4 = "\xAB".force_encoding 'ASCII-8BIT'
puts "s3 == s4: #{s3 == s4}"
```

In Ruby 2.0.0p353 it prints:

```
s1 == s2: true
s3 == s4: false
```

I don't understand why s3 and s4 are not equal when s1 and s2 is. 0xAB is the ASCII code for '½', which as far as I know is representable in both ASCII-8BIT and UTF8.

Comment: `\0xAB` is also *not* `½` as a UTF-8 character code. I found this: `"\xAB".force_encoding('CP850').encode('UTF-8')` - gives `½` . . . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850 - probably a few other MSDOS-based extensions have this mapping too.

Comment: I don't know where you got your info about that being the ASCII code for 1/2.  It is actually the [Left-pointing double angle quotation mark, left pointing guillemet](http://www.ascii-code.com/).  Did you mean `\xBD`?

Comment: 0xAB is not ASCII, and [0xAB] is not a valid UTF-8 string.

Answer (score 3):

`\xAB` in [utf-8](/questions/tagged/utf-8) isn't the same as `\xAB` in [ascii-8bit](/questions/tagged/ascii-8bit) [codepage](/questions/tagged/codepage), because to encode the *utf-8* is coded in multi-byte set, and chars from `\x80` to `\xff` is used to encode symbols with codes over `\x80`.

But since the *ASCII-8BIT* isn't specific encoding, but can be treated as the encoding class based on [ascii](/questions/tagged/ascii), and it is aliased to [binary](/questions/tagged/binary) encoding in [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby). The codes from from `\x80` to `\xff` can't also be converted any encoding. So it is like an abstraction for *ASCII* based-codepages.

So, if you try to convert from *ASCII-8BIT* to *utf-8* you would get the conversion exception:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError: "\xC9" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

However, you are able to handle `½` symbol properly in 8-bit encoding using explicitly set [iso-8859-1](/questions/tagged/iso-8859-1) or [cp1252](/questions/tagged/cp1252) codepages, and char `\xBD` as follows:

```
"\xBD".force_encoding('ISO-8859-1').encode('UTF-8')
# => "½"
"\xBD".force_encoding('CP1252').encode('UTF-8')
# => "½"
```